# sssd and ldap authentication cache

Tags: ldap, cache, latency, sssd

On our box running OpenSUSE 12.2 we have installed OpenLDAP and `sssd` daemon. We are using these two services for user authentication. Recently we created a script which creates new web-users for our vhosts dynamically, but now we are dealing with a problem.

It seems that sssd uses some kind of cache and during `getent passwd` it returns users that have been deleted from LDAP. Sometimes it doesn't return recently created user immediately as it is necessary further in the script (for setting permissions with `setfacl` and `chown`).

Restarting LDAP, `sssd` or `nscd` doesn’t help, neither flushing cache with `sss_cache -U`. We tried lowering cache in config of `sssd` but it seems that it doesn’t affect anything.

We need to somehow explicitly refresh the cache after adding new user to LDAP or disable the cache at all.

Has anyone experienced similar issue?

Answer (score 6):

From the man page (sssd.conf):

```
NSS configuration options
       These options can be used to configure the Name Service Switch (NSS)
       service.

       enum_cache_timeout (integer)
           How many seconds should nss_sss cache enumerations (requests for
           info about all users)
       Default: 120
```

I would insert something like:

```
[nss]
enum_cache_timeout 10
```

(adjust seconds as it seems fit)

Answer (score 6):

Try `sss_cache -E`

or try stopping sssd, removing the files in /var/lib/sss/db/*, and restarting sssd

Answer (score 3):

You could try to disable caching credentials by adding directive to /etc/sssd/sssd.conf:

```
[domain/default]
cache_credentials = False
```

You may then verify that sssd uses cache on credentials with console command:

```
# authconfig --test|grep credential
credential caching in SSSD is disabled
```

Comment: authconfig is redhat command, the problem is about OpenSUSE 12.2

Comment: cache_credentials is about credentials; question is about caching of users lookup.

Answer (score 3):

I have expierenced similar issues

I noticed that `getent passwd | grep <username>` and
`getent passwd <username>` will not return the same results,

Using strace I found that `getent passwd <username>` checks data in `"/var/lib/sss/mc/passwd"`

wheras `getent passwd | grep <username>` will connect to `/var/lib/sss/pipes/nss` and get it's data from there.

This is really confusing me, since both approaches seem to hit different caches. These caches seem to get updated when I run `sudo su - <username>` but seem to otherwise be valid for hours.

The result in practice is that e.g. ssh access won't work for a user a few minutes after it is removed from the ldap, but getent passwd will keep on showing it for hours, so it's hard for me to check if this users is in fact removed or not (without clearing some caches manually all the time)

Disabling caches is not an option in this case, having 2000+ users running jobs on 2000+ servers.

Answer (score 2):

- You can't disable caching completely with sssd.
- You can disable sss as an authentication provider completely and just query LDAP directly if that's what you want.

For example, in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, change lines like:

```
passwd:     files sss
```

to

```
passwd:     files ldap
```

- You can force cleaning of the cache by removing `/var/lib/sss/db/*`

Comment: This is wrong. There's a configuration directive that controls caching.

Comment: Are you referring to `cache_credentials`?  Does that disable all caching or just credentials, as the name would imply?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that having cache_credentials = True in Fedora 30/31 gives an error that makes impossible to login using LDAP users. I haven't found a documented bug related to this so I write it here.